# JSON parse in iphone Application

Tags: iphone, ios, json

I am new in iphone development. I want to use parse with Json framework in my iphone application. Can anybody provide me guideline or a good tutorial link .Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean this [Json framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) you can simply call

```
NSString *jsonString = // String in json format
SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSError *error = nil;
[jsonParser objectWithString:jsonString error:&error];
```

Full api doc is [here](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/api/3.0/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the best approach would be to use [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (for > iOS 5), for iOS 4.x versions use [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit). Both of them take JSON as input and produce NSDictionaries with appropriate data objects inside.

No need to parse the JSON yourself, if the tools out there are faster and easier to use. Also, both of my solutions have a nice documentation you can look through to get you started.