# Processing JSON output in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I made a very simple wordpress plugin that prints some posts in JSON format. I was wondering what is the best and simplest way is to process that information in Xcode.

I've seen many examples and many frameworks but I would like to hear your opinion and maybe some example code?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON parse in iphone Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340169/json-parse-in-iphone-application)

Comment: Possible what? I am just asking a question?

Comment: If your question is “how do I parse JSON in iOS?” it is an exact duplicate of the question I linked.  The word “possible” was stuck in there automatically by stackoverflow.  If your question is “what's your opinion of the best JSON parser?”, then “this question will likely solicit opinion” and is therefore “not constructive”.  Example code is trivial to find using google.

Comment: Thank you for your answer on my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting iOS 5.0 and later, the simplest way is using the [`NSJSONSerialization` class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that Apple provides.

Comment: Thank you. I am going to test that class.

Answer (score 0):

As rob said if you're targeting iOS 5 use Apples `NSJSONSerialization` class. For earlier iOS versions there area also some options:

- [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) (fastest)
- [SBJson](http://stig.github.com/json-framework)
- and others ...